# node.js autoscaling/load balancing any methods? with socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy a node.js project so it can auto scale with a loadbalancer.

I have tried AWS ELB elastic beanstalk. After a much time spent, the ELB doesn't like the socket.io connect as much as expected.

From this I have searched many methods to fix this issue:

- nginx proxying
- changed listeners on the loadbalancer to allow TCP port 3000 (other ports too depending on the forum/question I looked at)
- redis server to share socket connection between different nodes.

I can't really put all the sites that I've tried to get this working.
But it hasn't worked at all.

The only thing I probably haven't tried is using route53...

So the question is:

If there is someone that has a proper node.js app with socket.io working with elastic beanstalk (or EC2 instances with a load balancer and auto scaling) working, is there a way to do this, and what would that method be?

If there are links that have a few step by step methods that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance!